# Defining Public Functions within the Constructor using __proto__ in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

To my understanding, if I created a private variable with my constructor, prototyped functions could not access it.  For example:

```
var ClassTwo = function() {
    var prop = 1;
}
// This will error out when called.
ClassTwo.prototype.init = function() {
    try {
        console.log( "prop is ", prop );
    } catch(e){
        console.error( "prop is undefined" );
    }
}
```

However, with `__proto__` I found I can access the prototype within the constructor, and thus this is possible:

```
var ClassOne = function() {

    var prop = 1;

    this.__proto__.init = function() {
        console.log( "prop is ", prop ); // Will work!
    }
}
```

You can see it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/574h8fkL/1/

When I inspect the objects ClassOne and ClassTwo, the both appear to have init() function in their prototypes.  So, it appears this is working, or am I fooling myself?  Is this consider good or bad practice to define functions this way?

Comment: _"am I fooling myself?"_ Yes. Or don't you want a variable per instance? _"Is this consider good or bad practice to define functions this way?"_ You shouldn't use `__proto__`.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why this was made accessible in ES6.  What use cases would I want to use `__proto__` in?  If none, then why add it?  Unfortunately, the MDN article doesn't explain it to me in a way I understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto